# Problems compiling scangearmp

Tags: apt

I have already installed some missing packages, but i still get that error. Can anyone help me identify what is missing ? Thanks a lot

```
psr@psr-EasyNote-TM85:~/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/psr/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/psr/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp/po'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/psr/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp/po'
Making all in backend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/psr/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp/backend'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I. -I./include   -DV_MAJOR=2 -DV_MINOR=1 -O2 -D__GIMP_PLUGIN_ENABLE__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MT libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.Tpo -c -o libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.lo `test -f 'canon_mfp_tools.c' || echo './'`canon_mfp_tools.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I. -I./include -DV_MAJOR=2 -DV_MINOR=1 -O2 -D__GIMP_PLUGIN_ENABLE__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -MT libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.Tpo -c canon_mfp_tools.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.o
canon_mfp_tools.c:40:17: fatal error: usb.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libsane_canon_mfp_la-canon_mfp_tools.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/psr/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp/backend'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/psr/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
psr@psr-EasyNote-TM85:~/Downloads/scangearmp-source-2.10-1/scangearmp$
```

Comment: You should add your Ubuntu version to questions like this. It is probably missing either `libusb-dev` or `libusb-1.0-0-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `scangearmp-common` without difficult compilation methods with [**ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk**](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk) Repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install scangearmp-common
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would be nice, but when i try to install  scangearmp-common i get : E: Unable to locate package scangearmp-common